# What decides whether RegisterTypeLib writes to win32 or win64?

Tags: windows, com, atl, typelib

I am working with two ATL-based COM projects.

The both implement `DllRegisterServer` as just

```
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
  // registers object, typelib and all interfaces in typelib
  return _Module.RegisterServer(TRUE);
}
```

which ends up calling

```
::RegisterTypeLib(pTypeLib, bstrPath, szDir);
```

in atlbase.h:6516.

But for some reason this call makes one of the projects create

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\<guid>\<version>\0\win64
```

when registered using regsvr32.exe on Windows 7 32 bit.

The other project correctly creates

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\<guid>\<version>\0\win32
```

.

Where should I start looking to find and fix this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is strongly possible, that the typelibrary is targeted for the win64 platform.
Check the typelibary's attributes. One may access them via [ITypeLib::GetLibAttr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
ITypeLib::GetLibAttr(TLIBATTR **ppTLibAttr)
```

The TLIBATTR structure has a field of type [SYSKIND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It contains a value which indicates the platform.

```
typedef enum tagSYSKIND {
  SYS_WIN16   = 0,
  SYS_WIN32   = ( SYS_WIN16 + 1 ),
  SYS_MAC     = ( SYS_WIN32 + 1 ),
  SYS_WIN64   = ( SYS_MAC + 1 ) 
} SYSKIND;
```

I hope this will help you to solve the problem

Comment: Yes, this should be set by the midl.exe /env command line option.

Answer (score 2):

You are building either `Win32` DLL or `x64` DLL, and the type library is an attached resource. As you have discovered ATL projects use `RegisterTypeLib` API to have the type library registered, and API will register under bitness of the library resource (that is, normally it is original target platform).

I suppose you obtained `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TypeLib\<guid>\<version>\0\win64` registration by building/registering `x64` configuration.

Another possible cause is that under Project Setting in Visual Studio, under MIDL, General the `Target Environment` is set incorrectly - this might end up in registering `Win32` DLL resource under `win64` subkey.