# .NET COM Interface Method Signature Location In Windows Registry?

Tags: c#, .net, com

The COM interface for my .NET assembly used to define a method with a signature like this:

```
GePoint Point(double X, double Y, double Z);
```

I changed it to this:

```
GePoint Point();
```

The AutoCAD VBA (64-bit) code that uses the library is whining about the argument not being optional so I assume it is still seeing the first signature.  I'm further guessing this signature lives in the registry somewhere, but I could easily be mistaken.  Because of dependencies on AutoCAD dlls that can only be loaded in AutoCAD, I can't use the Windows regasm tool for register/unregister so I'm doing it from inside AutoCAD using registration services:

```
RegistrationServices rs;
rs = new RegistrationServices();
// To register
rs.RegisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),
                               AssemblyRegistrationFlags.SetCodeBase);
// To unregister
rs.UnregisterAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Maybe there is a way to easily clean out all references to the assembly, and types and methods defined therein?

Comment: When you re-register a COM object (DLL, TLB, etc.), it should overwrite old information (in most cases, like this one - one method signature). If it does not, it means you're not re-registering where you initially did. Maybe a 32-64 bit issue? Check this http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2010/06/01/com-and-registry/ and this http://mariusbancila.ro/blog/2010/11/04/32-bit-and-64-bit-com-servers/

Comment: If I recall correctly, VBA caches type information when you add a reference to a COM object. Try dropping it from the project, and then adding it back.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Believe me, I've tried that, but without much result.

Comment: @SimonMourier Looking at your accepted answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487332/how-to-programmatically-register-set-correct-path-to-a-type-library-from-withi, it seems I need to create and register the type library because I didn't do that in my RegistrationServices code.  VBA is using the .tlb file I generated with regasm by leaving the interface signatures the same and removing all dependencies on the AutoCAD dlls. I hope I can translate the VB .NET code example successfully.  I wonder if VBA truly requires the tlb?  Maybe only if early binding is desired?

Comment: @BH - I don't know how AutoCAD works, but yes, it's possible that you did register a typelib once using regasm or something else and never updated it since. VBA does not strictly require a typelib, but if there's one, it will use it. You can see if there's a typelib registered if you have intellisense support for your object in a VBA host (like Excel for example - or maybe AutoCAD if it uses VBA). If you have a typelib, then your code must call RegisterTypeLib.

Comment: @SimonMourier Yes, I think I got this all working the other day - thanks to your help and the other SO question - and I'll post the solution when I get time. AutoCAD VBA works pretty much the same as MS Office VBA. I don't want to entirely rewrite that VBA project because it has somewhere around 150K lines of code in it.

Answer (score 0):

The method signatures are not stored in the registry. The registry normally has the location of the COM component.

Are you able to register you COM component using [regsvr32](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/regsvr32) ?

> Regsvr32 is a command-line utility to register and unregister OLE controls, such as DLLs and ActiveX controls in the Windows Registry

Open a command prompt with admin rights and run `Regsvr32 path/to/your/com dll`

You can then check whether your program is picking up the new method signature.

Comment: I can't use regsvr32 because, as I said, my assembly has dependencies on AutoCAD dlls that can only be loaded in AutoCAD.  However, by removing the AutoCAD dependencies and just having only a skeleton class, I *was* able to register with regsvr32 and build the typelib file (.tlb). That's how I created my problem - I then changed my mind about the method signatures, etc.  I have this all figured out and working now so I'll post a solution when I get time.

Comment: I can also confirm your statement that the method signatures are not stored in the registry - probably in the tlb file, instead.  The tlb file location IS stored in the registry and you can make all of the code fairly angry by moving or deleting it, as I found.